# Do I split before or after cleaning code?

Tags: missing-data, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset in excel with thousands of rows and columns data, with a lot missing data, do I split the data including this missing data or not? I read [here](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/07/easy-guide-data-preprocessing-python.html) tut the dataset is split before cleaning. However, on this [repository](https://github.com/alod83/data-science/tree/master/Preprocessing) there is no splitting of data.

Is there a correct way or does it depend on the particular data?

Comment: Splitting data into train and test data sets to evaluate your [prediction model]?

Comment: yes, or i just cleaning the data first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "cleaning". If you would be only removing the rows with missing data or using some automated script to fix things like typos, it wouldn't really matter. The biggest difference in such case would be that if you first split and then removed rows with missing data, the train/test proportions could potentially change.

On another hand, say that initially your cleaning step consisted of removing the rows with missing data. You did the splitting after the step. After some consideration, you decided that instead of removing the rows, you would impute the missing data. If you introduce the change, now you would be leaking the data, since the imputation would be done before splitting, so it will "know" some of the characteristics of the whole dataset.

Splitting the data as the **first step** prevents from the potential problems as described above. If your code runs on train set independently of test set, there is no chance of a leak, no matter what the code does.

Comment: Hi! thanks! I got it, I wanna ask more can I? after I analyze more in my dataset there is a duplicate, and need some normalizing the dataset itself for text like capitalization, did I must cleaning or split then?

Comment: @uzrsa as said above, the safest option is usually to write code in such way that you do splitting first and then have a preprocessing pipeline that can run on train and test set separately, or even be re-used in cross-validation when needed.